# jQuery: unwrap() deletes additional parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the container *.vorteile* wrapped in *.vorteile_outer* by jQuery. When I want to remove *.vorteile_outer* using `.unwrap()` on *.vorteile*, the parent container of *.vorteile_outer* which is *#template_footer_vorteile* also gets removed.

Here is the jquery part (in full context it is in a function).

```
$('.vorteil, :vorteil_outer:not').unwrap();
```

And here the HTML part

```
<div id="template_footer_vorteile">
    <div class="vorteil_outer">
        <div class="vorteil kunden">
            <p class="titel">kundenzufriedenheit</p>
            <p class="desc">kundenzufriedenheitText</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vorteil_outer">
        <div class="vorteil tradition">
            <p class="titel">tradition</p>
            <p class="desc">traditionText</p>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `$('.vorteil').unwrap();` will do... what is the selector `:vorteil_outer:not` suppose to do

Comment: Weird, it throws a syntax error. It shouldn't even remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just give like this

```
$("p").unwrap();  // vorteil class div removed
$('.vorteil').unwrap(); // vorteil_outer div removed
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T2zkz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove 'template_footer_vorteile' then try this :

```
$('.vorteil').parent().unwrap();
```

and if you want to remove only "vorteil_outer" and retain the "template_footer_vorteile" then try this :

```
$('.vorteil').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `.vorteile_outer` you always have to apply `unwrap` to `vorteil` (ie) when you want to remove the `div` apply `unwrap` to the child of that `div`.

```
var gs = $("div.vorteil");
$("button").click(function () {
    if (gs.parent().is("div.vorteil_outer")) {
       gs.unwrap();
    }
});
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aT9Z/6/)

To know about unwrap visit http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/